# Where is the Groovy/Grails support in NetBeans?

Tags: java, grails, netbeans, groovy

After repeatedly hearing good things about the Grails support in NetBeans and being frustrated by eclipse's lack thereof, I've decided to give it a try, but now said support doesn't seem to exist:

- I've downloaded the bunde containing NetBeans 6.7 along with the latest Java 5 JDK from Sun
- The About box says: NetBeans IDE 6.7 (Build 200906241340)
- But the 'Groovy' category in the New Project wizard [described here](http://grails.org/NetBeans+Integration) does not exist.
- The Help docs od NetBeans have a section "Enabling a Java Application to Support Groovy"
- It mentions a Groovy category in the Project Properties which, again, does not exist

So what's wrong here? Is this a stripped-down version of NetBeans? Can I update it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download any version of [Netbeans 6.7](http://www.netbeans.org/downloads/index.html) and Groovy/Grails is either included or easily installed from the Tools->Plugin menu.  The chart on the page specifies what is included in each download package.

If Groovy/Grails is not shown on the **Installed** tab you can install it from the **Available Plugins** tab.   There is a **Search** box where you can type Groovy to find the plugin.  Note the **Show Details** checkbox will show more plugins in the **Installed** tab.

Also note one of the advantages of getting a smaller Netbeans build is that it will start faster.  It is better to start with the smallest download and add the plugins that you need.